# não consigo encontrar o meu erro

Tags: javascript

Esse código funciona no topo do meu site (menu), e estou tentando usar ele também no rodapé, já que tenho a aba de registro tanto no topo quanto no rodapé, mas no rodapé ele não funciona.

Alguém pode me ajudar a encontrar o erro? ou é simplesmente impossível utilizar o mesmo código no topo e no rodapé? Lembrando que estou criando todas as páginas separadas (rodapé é uma página, menu é outra, e juntando elas com php. Por esse motivo, acredito eu, que não deveria dar erro, já que, supostamente, não estão em contato direto uma página com a outra.

Alguém pode me ajudar no que devo fazer para que funcione nas duas páginas? Tenho que mudar ou acrescentar algo?

```js
function valida_campos() {
  if (document.getElementById('name').value == '') {
    alert('The field name is obrigatory.');
    document.getElementById('name').focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('lastname').value == '') {
    alert('The field lastname is obrigatory.');
    document.getElementById('lastname').focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('birthday').value == '') {
    alert('Field birthday is obrigatory.');
    document.getElementById('birthday').focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('email').value == '') {
    alert('The field email obrigatory.');
    document.getElementById('email').focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('password').value == '' || document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('password2').value) {
    alert('Password didnt mach, please try again.');
    document.getElementById('password').focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form class="default-form" action="cadastrar.php" method="post" onSubmit="return valida_campos();">


  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="birthday" id="birthday" type="text" placeholder="birthday d/m/y">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="password2" id="password2" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password">
  </p>

  <input type="submit" placeholder="cadastrar">

</form>
```

Comment: Mikaela, dei um edit na pergunta. O erro que tens está presente na pergunta agora editada/formatada?

Comment: Eu dei submit pelo jsfiddle e foi, tem certeza que está com erro?

Comment: Testei também, quando os campos estão preenchidos ele identifica corretamente. Pergunta: no `onSubmit` precisar do `return`?

Comment: Acho que é indiferente a existência desse return

Comment: @LaércioLopes, @WesleyNascimento,  esse `return` [é importante](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/229559/129).

Comment: Pode ser outro script no seu site, porque também testei aqui e esta funcionando normalmente.

Comment: entao, eu também fiz o teste, estou usando esse script no topo (menu) e no rodapé do meu site, no topo funciona perfeitamente, mas no rodape fica dando erro, da erro em todos os input conectados com javascipt...

Comment: Qual é o erro? Ainda não falou.

Comment: isso de usar o código no topo e rodape ... aba de registro tanto no topo quanto no rodapé .... não estão em contato direto uma pagina com a outra... Está meio confuso!! Melhor postar tudo na pergunta.

Comment: O que você tem no topo e rodape? o mesmo formulario para trabalhar com o script?

Comment: Ela só descreveu o que está fazendo e que está dando erro, mas não disse qual é o erro (formulário não envia, javascript não responde, formulário em branco etc)... Pelo que percebi, talvez ela esteja usando o mesmo formulário no topo e no rodapé, aí o Javascript vai pegar apenas o formulário do topo, mesmo usando a do rodapé.

Comment: Deve tah gerando duplicidade de formulário. Neste caso, terá na mesma página dois formulários idênticos, e o Javascript irá considerar apenas o primeiro. A solução é criar um mecanismo para diferenciar um formulário do outro, ou então (pra mim a melhor forma) é usar o formulário de forma dinâmica, puxando o HTML do formulário de acordo com o local em que foi chamado (topo ou rodapé).

Comment: assim, eu tenho 3 paginas, o index, o rodape e o topo, todas em php, no index, eu inclui o todo e o rodape, quando eu rodo o script no topo, da tudo certo, tudo ok, quando eu rodo o script no rodape, ele fica aparecendo que os campos estao vazios, todos eles, essa é a minha pergunta, mesmo estando em paginas separadas, eu nao consigo utilizar o mesmo formulario? Com o mesmo script em javascript?

Comment: O problema não é no script em si. Colocando o formulário no topo e no rodapé, vc está colocando o mesmo formulário 2 vezes na mesma página, e o Javascript irá reconhecer apenas o primeiro. Por isso quando vc preenche o formulário no rodapé, o Javascript irá verificar o do topo que está em branco.

Comment: Coloca na pergunta o código que vc faz com que o formulário apareça no topo e aí podemos achar uma solução fácil pra isso. Ou ele já aparece no carregamento da página sem precisar clicar em nada?

Comment: Galera, agradeço muito a ajuda, consegui arrumar, troquei o ID dos campos do formulário e do javascript do rodapé e agora está funcionando 100%, =DDD

Comment: Isso dá certo mesmo, mas não é a melhor prática ficar com dois formulários praticamente repetidos. Quando vc quiser fazer alguma alteração em um, terá que fazer nos dois. Mas se está dando certo, sucesso!

Comment: to me debatendo mas to aprendendo hahaha, ainda tenho que descobrir como colocar os 2 em um só sem dar problemas, mas confesso que, mesmo tendo mais trabalho, estou feliz de ter conseguido hehehe

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma de deixar os dois formulários repetidos e o mesmo JavaScript que faz a validação é identificar qual formulário está sendo usado (do topo ou do rodapé) e validar apenas este (ignorando o outro) é usando o código abaixo (requer jQuery):

Coloque no `<form>` o parâmetro `this` no `onsubmit` que servirá pra identificar o formulário, desta forma:

```
onSubmit="return valida_campos(this);"
```

> A vantagem de usar o `this` é que deixará seu código bem mais enxuto e
>   fácil de trabalhar, além de diminuir os *byte*s da sua página, melhorando a performance.

Adicione a variável `i` na função que irá receber esse parâmetro:

```
function valida_campos(i) {....
```

No início da função, adicione o código:

```
for(x=0;x<=$(".default-form").length;x++){
    if($(i).index() != x){
        formulario = $(".default-form:eq("+x+")").detach();
    }
}
```

> Este código irá identificar qual dos dois formulário foi usado e
>   "destacar" o outro, tornando-o fora do escopo do JavaScript.

Seu código completo ficaria assim:

**HTML**

```
<form class="default-form" action="cadastrar.php" method="post" onSubmit="return valida_campos(this);">
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="name" id="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="lastname" id="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="birthday" id="birthday" type="text" placeholder="birthday d/m/y">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="email" id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password">
  </p>
  <p class="form-row">
    <input name="password2" id="password2" type="password" placeholder="Repeat Password">
  </p>

  <input type="submit" placeholder="cadastrar" value="ok">
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function valida_campos(i) {

    for(x=0;x<=$(".default-form").length;x++){
        if($(i).index() != x){
            formulario = $(".default-form:eq("+x+")").detach();
        }
    }

  if (i.name.value == '') {
    alert('The field name is obrigatory.');
    i.name.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (i.lastname.value == '') {
    alert('The field lastname is obrigatory.');
    i.lastname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (i.birthday.value == '') {
    alert('Field birthday is obrigatory.');
    i.birthday.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (i.email.value == '') {
    alert('The field email obrigatory.');
    i.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if (i.password.value == '' || i.password.value != i.password2.value) {
    alert('Password didnt mach, please try again.');
    i.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```